# Is "scope" a standard claim?

Tags: jwt, identityserver4, openid-connect

Is there any standard `scope` claim in OpenID Connect, JWT or OAuth?

In the [IdentityServer 4 documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html#authorization-based-on-scopes), there is a "scope" which is a space-separated string.

```json
{
  "client_id": "mobile_app",
  "sub": "123",
  "scope": "read write delete"
}
```

But from my IdentityServer 4 instance, I get a "scope" claim in the access token which is a array of strings.

```json
{
  // ...
  "client_id": "mobile_app",
  "sub": "123",
  "scope": [ "openid", "profile", "email", "offline_access" ],
  "amr": [ "pwd" ]
}
```

In the [OpenID Connect Core 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ClaimsContents) specification, I do not see "scope" listed as a claim.
In the [RFC 7519](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1) JSON Web Token (JWT) specification, I do not see "scope" listed as a claim.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `scope` claim was standardized by the [Token Exchange](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8693) RFC. According to the spec it should be a JSON string, with a space-separated scope tokens.

> The value of the "scope" claim is a JSON string containing a space-separated list of scopes associated with the token...

Comment: Except when [you're Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests), then it's an array :-/

Answer (score 2):

Most providers supports the AT+JWT token type and in it is specified that it should include a scope claim:

- [JSON Web Token (JWT) Profile for OAuth 2.0 Access Tokens](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-bertocci-oauth-access-token-jwt-00.html#rfc.section.2.2.2)

It says:

> If an authorization request includes a scope parameter, the
> corresponding issued JWT access token MUST include a scope claim as
> defined in section 4.2 of [TokenExchange].
>
> All the individual scopes strings in the scope claim MUST have meaning
> for the resource indicated in the aud claim.