# When I name the token "jwt" in Postman and use it in the post operation for authentication, it gives a 401 error

Tags: python, jwt, postman, fastapi

These are a part of my path operations

[image]

This is my postman interface to name the token

[image]

There is no problem in get operation

[image]

But I am taking error in post operation

[image]

I controlled my path operations but I can't see the mistake. Can you help me please

Comment: Change from 'pm.response.json().access_token' to  'pm.response.json().token'

Comment: 401 means the token allow get but not allow create. So you needs login user give a create role(or scope) by Admin.  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70168487/is-scope-a-standard-claim)